# Drag 'n' Drop text into TinyMCE won't work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, tinymce

I've built a little email sending thing for a part of our software. It uses TinyMCE for basic text styling. I have placeholders which are converted in the backend, and these can be dragged and dropped onto the TinyMCE interface rather than the user typing them out. It works in every browser perfectly. Except in IE it shows a stop sign cursor and won't allow it. The text is being held on the cursor, and I can drop it into other input fields, but not the TinyMCE editor. Any idea what this could be?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of IE are you working with? My best guess, it's not a features in Internet bugExplorer and is therefor impossible to achieve.

Comment: The live demo on TinyMCE (http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) seems to work with Drag&Drop on IE. Could you please show us the problem with one of your page?

Comment: The issue is, that the TinyMCE editor has a P tag ready for typing into. In other browsers, I can drag and drop text onto ANY area of the editor window and it'll be dropped into that P tag. In IE9, (may be other versions too) it will only let me drop the text into the P tag itself, which may only be 12px tall, so it's not intuitive that you can drop text into it... To simulate the issue with the live demo, clear it's contents, and try to drop text into it. Unless you drop over the 12px tall area of the P tag, you can't drop.

Answer (score 0):

would it help you to change those p to brs? if it does, then you can change them with this code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   forced_root_block : false,
   force_br_newlines : true,
   force_p_newlines : false
});
```

More information here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#TinyMCE_produce_P_elements_on_enter.2Freturn_instead_of_BR_elements.3F

Comment: I added my answer almost a week ago, wanted to opt for the bounty... too bad no one read the thread.